# what functions does libstdc++.so provide?

Tags: c++

Almost all real executable c++ programs link to libstdc++.so. What kind of functions does this shared library provide?

I thought that much work is done in compile time, such as template instantiation, which can't be done before compiling.

Comment: It provides ALL the functions that ARE NOT templates and inlines.

Comment: There's a lot of the standard library that is an actual library e.g. not just templatized code.

Comment: @MatsPetersson What about libc?

Comment: libc contains C standard library functions. I mean that libstdc++ contains all the functions not that are in the C++ standard (but not in the C standard).

Comment: And probably a few template explicit specializations and explicit instantiations too.  Also, sometimes a public template function will call a private non-template function to do some of its work, and those non-template functions would be in the linkable library.

Comment: As well as standard functions, I believe it also contains a lot of the C++-specific runtime stuff (exception handling and whatnot).

Comment: As well as run-time type information, and a lot more.

Comment: It's a great question.  Helped me.  I'd say that's constructive.  Thanks guys who closed it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

libstdc++ provides run-time support for user-space C++ applications. What is in that library is implementation specific, and may change from one release to the next one. You shouldn't probably rely on what is there.

Putting theory aside, shared libraries always export symbols such as functions and/or data. There are a number of tools you can use to see those symbols. One of those is [`nm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html); it would display the dynamic symbols if you specify `-D` argument. So let's do it on libstdc++.so. (The list is quite big, so I've used `head -20` to limit it.)

```
$ nm -D /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | head -20
                 U abort
                 U __assert_fail
000000386565d2b0 T atomic_flag_clear_explicit
000000386565d2f0 T __atomic_flag_for_address
000000386565d2a0 T atomic_flag_test_and_set_explicit
000000386565d2c0 T __atomic_flag_wait_explicit
                 U bindtextdomain
                 U btowc
                 U __ctype_get_mb_cur_max
000000386565dd10 T __cxa_allocate_dependent_exception
000000386565dae0 T __cxa_allocate_exception
                 U __cxa_atexit
000000386565df10 T __cxa_bad_cast
000000386565df50 T __cxa_bad_typeid
000000386565dfe0 T __cxa_begin_catch
000000386565eb10 T __cxa_call_unexpected
000000386565f160 T __cxa_current_exception_type
000000386565fa00 T __cxa_deleted_virtual
0000003865668990 T __cxa_demangle
000000386565e050 T __cxa_end_catch
```

Those are just some functions provided by the C++ runtime. In the above case, most of them are those implementing [Exception Handling according to Itanium C++ ABI](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/abi-eh-1.21.html).
Also note that C++ names could be mangled, so for example you can run into something that looks like *_ZSt9has_facetISt7codecvtIwc11__mbstate_tEEbRKSt6locale*. It could be pretty hard to demangle it yourself to understand what it means. So there is another tool called [`c++filt`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html) that can help with this, for example calling it as  `c++filt _ZSt9has_facetISt7codecvtIwc11__mbstate_tEEbRKSt6locale`.

You could even use it to demangle any symbol that appears to be mangled, as in `nm -D /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | c++filt`.

Of course, this would work with any shared object and not only C++ runtime.

Comment: Only the symbols marked `T` are actually provided by `libstdc++.so`, the rest is provided elsewhere.

Comment: @rubenvb: Not necessarily, but you still have a good point. `T` means “The symbol is in the text (code) section.”, `V` for example, would be a weak symbol which is also provided, but would be overridden if provided elsewhere. The list of those abbreviations is the first thing in “DESCRIPTION” section of nm's manual page.

Comment: Right, I normally see Windows stuff, so only `U` and `T` for me :)

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to have the list of function that are explicitly defined in the library, you may use the `nm` command on the library file :

`nm -D -C -g --defined-only /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.so  | less`

If will be huge, exhaustive... But it shows you what is exported.